# Why is this inner loop being performed in my insertion sort algorithm?

Tags: java, arrays, conditional-statements, insertion-sort

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but finding the correct answer on here was always going to be difficult.

Here's my code:

```
public class InsertionSort2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {                                
    int[] input = { 4, 2, 9, 6, 23, 12, 34, 0, 1 };
    insertionSort(input);
    }

private static void printNumbers(int[] input) {
    System.out.print("\n" + "THis is the sorted array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(input[i] + ", ");
    System.out.println("\n");
    }

public static void insertionSort(int array[]) {
    int n = array.length;
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) { // int j is the index in the array that is being compared to the key
    int key = array[j]; // the key is the actual number of the array index j
    int i = j-1;  // int i is the index right before j (one less than j)
    System.out.print("\n" + "outer Loop j = " + j);
    System.out.print("\n" + "outer Loop i = " + i);
    System.out.print("\n" + "outer Loop key = " + key + "\n");
    while ( (i > -1) && ( array [i] > key ) ) { // this is where the comparison of the numbers takes place
        System.out.print("\n" + "inner Loop array [i] (this is the lower index in the array) = " + array [i]); // array [i] refers to the value of number at the position i.
        System.out.print("\n" + "inner Loop array [i+1] (this is the higher index in the array) = " + array [i+1]); // this is the value of the number one higher in the array
        array [i+1] = array [i]; // here the system puts the higher value into the lower value's spot
        i--;
        System.out.print("\n" + "inner Loop [i--] = " + i);
            }
    array[i+1] = key; // here the program changes the key to be the next item in the array so that it can go through the for loop again.            
  printNumbers(array);
    }
}
}
```

And here's the output:

```
outer Loop j = 1
outer Loop i = 0
outer Loop key = 2

inner Loop array [i] = 4
inner Loop array [i+1] = 2
inner Loop [i--] = -1
THis is the sorted array: 2, 4, 9, 6, 23, 12, 34, 0, 1, 


outer Loop j = 2
outer Loop i = 1
outer Loop key = 9

THis is the sorted array: 2, 4, 9, 6, 23, 12, 34, 0, 1, 


outer Loop j = 3
outer Loop i = 2
outer Loop key = 6

inner Loop array [i] = 9
inner Loop array [i+1] = 6
inner Loop [i--] = 1
THis is the sorted array: 2, 4, 6, 9, 23, 12, 34, 0, 1, 


outer Loop j = 4
outer Loop i = 3
outer Loop key = 23

THis is the sorted array: 2, 4, 6, 9, 23, 12, 34, 0, 1, 


outer Loop j = 5
outer Loop i = 4
outer Loop key = 12

inner Loop array [i] = 23
inner Loop array [i+1] = 12
inner Loop [i--] = 3
THis is the sorted array: 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 23, 34, 0, 1, 


outer Loop j = 6
outer Loop i = 5
outer Loop key = 34

THis is the sorted array: 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 23, 34, 0, 1, 


outer Loop j = 7
outer Loop i = 6
outer Loop key = 0

inner Loop array [i] = 34
inner Loop array [i+1] = 0
inner Loop [i--] = 5
inner Loop array [i] = 23
inner Loop array [i+1] = 34
inner Loop [i--] = 4
inner Loop array [i] = 12
inner Loop array [i+1] = 23
inner Loop [i--] = 3
inner Loop array [i] = 9
inner Loop array [i+1] = 12
inner Loop [i--] = 2
inner Loop array [i] = 6
inner Loop array [i+1] = 9
inner Loop [i--] = 1
inner Loop array [i] = 4
inner Loop array [i+1] = 6
inner Loop [i--] = 0
inner Loop array [i] = 2
inner Loop array [i+1] = 4
inner Loop [i--] = -1
THis is the sorted array: 0, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 23, 34, 1, 


outer Loop j = 8
outer Loop i = 7
outer Loop key = 1

inner Loop array [i] = 34
inner Loop array [i+1] = 1
inner Loop [i--] = 6
inner Loop array [i] = 23
inner Loop array [i+1] = 34
inner Loop [i--] = 5
inner Loop array [i] = 12
inner Loop array [i+1] = 23
inner Loop [i--] = 4
inner Loop array [i] = 9
inner Loop array [i+1] = 12
inner Loop [i--] = 3
inner Loop array [i] = 6
inner Loop array [i+1] = 9
inner Loop [i--] = 2
inner Loop array [i] = 4
inner Loop array [i+1] = 6
inner Loop [i--] = 1
inner Loop array [i] = 2
inner Loop array [i+1] = 4
inner Loop [i--] = 0
THis is the sorted array: 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 23, 34,
```

Why does the inner `while` loop get executed the first three times? It doesn't seem that the condition to execute the while loop has been met.

The system also prints what seems to be the opposite of what you would think in the instances where the while loop should not be run. The `array [i]` prints the correct array value, but the `array [i+1]` prints the wrong array value (one less instead of one greater).

Comment: Your code doesn't match your description is several ways.  You're going to need to learn to use a debugger.

Comment: The inner loop in an insertion sort if for shifting the values up until the element is in it's correct position. I'm not sure if that's what you actually wanted to know, please clarify your question.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Edited so hopefully that helps clarify the question.

Comment: there isn't anything wrong with the value of array[i+1], please explain what seems wrong to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain one of those multiple prints:

```
Why am I being run? //key=0 array[i]=34 -> array[i]>key -> 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 23, 34, 34, 1,
Why am I being run? //key=0 array[i]=23 -> array[i]>key -> 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 23, 23, 34, 1,
Why am I being run? //key=0 array[i]=12 -> array[i]>key -> 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 12, 34, 34, 1,
Why am I being run? //key=0 array[i]=9 -> array[i]>key -> 2, 4, 6, 9, 9, 23, 34, 34, 1,
Why am I being run? //key=0 array[i]=6 -> array[i]>key -> 2, 4, 6, 6, 12, 23, 34, 34, 1,
Why am I being run? //key=0 array[i]=4 -> array[i]>key -> 2, 4, 4, 9, 12, 23, 34, 34, 1,
Why am I being run? //key=0 array[i]=2 -> array[i]>key -> 2, 2, 6, 9, 12, 23, 34, 34, 1,
```

Then you reach the case where `i==-1` and end the loop

```
0, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 23, 34, 1,
```

Hope that helps you to understands how this algorithm works.

For the first 3 cases:

1rst:

```
j == 1
i == j-1 == 0
key == 2
array[i] == 4
```

so

```
((i>-1) && (array[i]>key)) == true
```

the loop while execute once then you got `i == i-- == -1` and the loop ends.

2nd case:

```
j == 2
i == j-1 == 1
key == 9
array[i] == 4
```

so

```
((i>-1) && (array[i]>key)) == false
```

the loop won't run

3rd case:

```
j == 3
i == j-1 == 2
key == 6
array[i] == 9
```

so

```
((i>-1) && (array[i]>key)) == true
```

the loop while run once then you got `i == i-- == 1` and `array[i]=4`. So `array[i]<key`, the loop ends.

And so on. I won't explain each case. Try to use a debugger.

Comment: I'm asking why the while loop is executed when the condition hasn't been met.